# Extract part of a dictionary within a list by string condition in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list with dictionary contained within it in the format:

```py
mydataset =
    [{'thing1': 'pink',
    'thing2': 'apple',
    'thing3': 'car',
    'data': [{'firstname': 'jenny',
        'lastname': 'jones',
        }]},
    {'thing1': 'blue',
    'thing2': 'banana',
    'thing3': 'bicycle',
    'data': [{'firstname': 'david',
        'lastname': 'walls',
        }]}]
```

I want to be able to extract all the items called `firstname` within 'data', i.e. `'jenny'` and `'david'`.

I've tried an approach of `myextract = [x in x if mydataset['data']]`, but of course it fails because I think I'm looking for a value with that. My mental model of the data structure isn't right at the moment.

Comment: `my_extract = [x["data"][0]["firstname"] for x in mydataset]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
res = [i['data'][0]['firstname'] for i in mydataset]
```

output:

```
['jenny', 'david']
```

side note: *please put banana and apple inside single quotes.*

Answer (score 1):

Use the following list comprehension:

```
res = [di["firstname"]for d in mydataset for di in d["data"] if "firstname" in di]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['jenny', 'david']
```

The above list comprehension is equivalent to the following for-loop:

```
res = []
for d in mydataset:
    for di in d["data"]:
        if "firstname" in di:
            res.append(di["firstname"])

print(res)
```

Note that both solutions above will work for more than one element in  the sub-dictionary `d["data"]` and even if the `"firstname"` key is not present.

For the sake of reusability you could also define a function that will let you access individual values in the dataset and use it for this particular example:

```
def nested_getitem(path, dic):
    from operator import getitem
    from functools import reduce
    return reduce(getitem, path, dic)


res = [nested_getitem(["data", 0, "firstname"], d) for d in mydataset]
print(res)
```

**Output**

```
['jenny', 'david']
```